# jsonpath query for reading json's child elements

Tags: json

I'm trying to read element's values.
For test purposes I was trying to read account_name element value.

I've tried this

```
jsonloop query = "data/ads/data/insights/data[*]"
account_name =  "$.data.ads.data.insights.data.[*].account_name"
```

But not getting result. Apart from this I've googled alot and my logic seems to be okay..but I dont know where am doing wrong.

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "id": "act_78425484545145418"
    }, {
        "id": "act_87814545415645416"
    }, {
        "ads": {
            "data": [{
                "insights": {
                    "data": [{
                        "account_name": "Emirates WW",
                        "campaign_name": "FR_Ozone_aug",
                        "adset_name": "Android",
                        "ad_name": "C_mail_9sept",
                        "spend": 12.2,
                        "impressions": "1146",
                        "clicks": "16",
                        "_store_clicks": "0",
                        "inline_click_pointss": "16",
                        "actions": [{
                            "action_type": "custom_event._activate_",
                            "value": 2
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "custom_event.other",
                            "value": 1
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "click_points",
                            "value": 16
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "__install",
                            "value": 1
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "offsite_points.view_content_points",
                            "value": 25
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "post_points",
                            "value": 16
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "post_points",
                            "value": 16
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "offsite_points",
                            "value": 25
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "custom_event",
                            "value": 3
                        }],
                        "date_start": "2016-09-09",
                        "date_stop": "2016-09-19"
                    }],
                    "paging": {
                        "cursors": {
                            "before": "ADZZZZ",
                            "after": "ADZZZZ"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": "6054027758549"
            }, {
                "insights": {
                    "data": [{
                        "account_name": "Emirates WW",
                        "campaign_name": "FR_Ozone_aug",
                        "adset_name": "Reta_Phy_iOS",
                        "ad_name": "Council_email_9sept",
                        "spend": 10.13,
                        "impressions": "1004",
                        "clicks": "10",
                        "_store_clicks": "8",
                        "inline_click_pointss": "10",
                        "actions": [{
                            "action_type": "click_points",
                            "value": 10
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "offsite_points.view_content_points",
                            "value": 38
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "post_points",
                            "value": 10
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "post_points",
                            "value": 10
                        }, {
                            "action_type": "offsite_points",
                            "value": 38
                        }],
                        "date_start": "2016-09-09",
                        "date_stop": "2016-09-19"
                    }],
                    "paging": {
                        "cursors": {
                            "before": "ADZZZZ",
                            "after": "ADZZZZ"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": "6054030075149"
            }],
            "paging": {
                "cursors": {
                    "before": "Juysubgysbyy",
                    "after": "Nhwunhseuubeyegb"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

First and second `data` properties have array values, so you should add `.[*]` after them:

```
account_name =  "$.data.[*].ads.data.[*].insights.data.[*].account_name"
```

The result:

```
[
  "Emirates WW",
  "Emirates WW"
]
```